# Text hides when framelayout is set to some custom background (how to not inherit style from parent)

Tags: android, xml

I have a custom drawable as a background to the root of my framelayout with opacity(alpha) of 0.1. I have a LinearLayout inside which has some TextView. When I set my TextViews to the color of my FrameLayout's color it disappears( with no opacity ). How can I set opacity to my background(FrameLayout) without affecting my textviews(child of Framelayout). I have tried a lot of ways but it always hides the textviews inside.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_img_bg"
    android:alpha="0.1"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"


        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Not Verified,"
            android:textSize="32dp"

            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorViews"
            <!-- colorViews same color as framelayout background color it diappears but why?-->
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </TextView>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:text="Sorry, We couldn't verify the mobile number ">

        </TextView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"

                android:src="@drawable/ic_icon_resentotp"

                ></ImageView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="Resend OTP"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorViews"

            >

        </View>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_icon_changemblno1"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </ImageView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Change mobile number"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, If someone is still looking for an answer then I have it over here!!

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent">


<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_img_bg"
    android:alpha="0.1"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


</FrameLayout>



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Not Verified,"
        android:textSize="32dp"

        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorViews"

    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</TextView>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:text="Sorry, We couldn't verify the mobile number ">

</TextView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"

        android:src="@drawable/ic_icon_resentotp"

        ></ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Resend OTP"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorViews"

    >

</View>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_icon_changemblno1"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change mobile number"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```